# Where place cleanup code in a WPF Page?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I've a wpf application. The mainWindow is composed of frames and in each frame I have a page.
When I close a Page I need to do some actions as cleanupcode, I tried to write this code in Page_Unloaded as follows

```
Private Sub Page_Unloaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    m_close = True
    Map_Unloaded(sender, e)

End Sub
```

Map_Unloaded contains de actions that I like to execute on close the Page.
Unload event is raised when user close the page but not where the mainwindow is closing.

Reading on msdn I didn't find any helpful information, I read this on it:

> Note that the Unloaded event is not raised after an application begins
>   shutting down. Application shutdown occurs when the condition defined
>   by the ShutdownMode property occurs. If you place cleanup code within
>   a handler for the Unloaded event, such as for a Window or a
>   UserControl, it may not be called as expected.

Thanks

Comment: How are you navigating to the Page ? Share some code. Also how or where are you unloading the Page?

Answer (score 0):

Wpf Window have Closing and Closed event that you can use.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.window.closed(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks, but i hope this is not an option because I'm not usuing a Window, I'm working on a Page. Events in both are different and this is my problem.